# Table has unique rows, however how can I find duplicates of certain columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table such that looks like the following:

```
ID         TID        TNAME     CID     CNAME     SEQUENCE
-----------------------------------------------------------
200649     6125     Schalke    356954   Mirko         1
200749     6125     Schalke    356954   Mirko         1
200849     6125     Schalke    439386   Fred          1
200849     6125     Schalke    356954   Mirko         1
200849     6125     Schalke    495881   Michael       1
200949     6125     Schalke    401312   Felix         1
200949     6125     Schalke    495881   Michael       2
```

I would like to query this table so it only returns if ID and SEQUENCE are duplicated. i.e. it should only return:

```
200849     6125     Schalke    439386   Fred          1
200849     6125     Schalke    356954   Mirko         1
200849     6125     Schalke    495881   Michael       1
```

I have used `having count(ID) > 1` but it will not return anything since CIDs are all unique.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a way to do it:

```
select a.*
from yourTable as a
inner join (
    select id, sequence 
    from yourTable 
    group by id, sequence 
    having count(id)>1) as b on a.id = b.id and a.sequence=b.sequence
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT b.id, 
       b.tid, 
       b.tname, 
       b.cid, 
       b.cname, 
       b.sequence 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               sequence, 
               Count(*) CNT 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY id, 
                  sequence 
        HAVING Count(*) > 1) a 
       LEFT JOIN table1 b 
              ON b.id = a.id 
                 AND b.sequence = a.sequence
```

**Result**

```
|     ID |  TID |   TNAME |    CID |   CNAME | SEQUENCE |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 200849 | 6125 | Schalke | 439386 |    Fred |        1 |
| 200849 | 6125 | Schalke | 356954 |   Mirko |        1 |
| 200849 | 6125 | Schalke | 495881 | Michael |        1 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc2a7/1)

Comment: You don't need to join on sequence - id is enough (it is the key after all - all other columns are unnecessary to identify the row)

Comment: @Bohemian If you were right, then there wouldn't be duplicate entries in the `Id` column

Comment: @Bohemian On second look, since `id` & `sequence` make the unique pair, I think `sequence` needs to be joined as well.

Comment: Wait! @Barranka is right. The id column is *not* an id column! Look at the data - id is not unique. At this point, the OP should probably rip it all up and start again :/

Comment: @Bohemian I think there's a unique composite key we're not seeing.

Comment: That's not the point: You should never name a column "id" unless it is unique. It's a convention that everyone follows (well until now)

Answer (score 2):

I like using analytic functions for these things:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, sequence) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
```

This also gives you the number of duplicates on each row in the output.

Comment: Was trying to use same approach. Use [this SQL Fiddle code sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/432b7/1) if you like.